# Only seeing white splash screen

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I try to load a loginView in my app delegate but it only shows the original white splash which sais something like "Welcome to universal app".

I am quite puzzled.

I have created a loginView.xib. Files Owner's class is LoginViewController.h. The view is linked to Files Owner.

I load the view like this in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
LoginViewController *loginVw = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

[self.window addSubview:loginVw.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: have you remove your splash view after loading the splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initialiser for a UIViewController backed by a XIB is `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle`.

Your code should look more like

```
LoginViewController *loginVw = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
```

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and sample code is your friend in this case.

Comment: @Chris two people told you the same thing in the same 60 seconds. You're going to have to provide more info then

Comment: OK. Solution was almost as expected. Xcode had a bad day I guess. I deleted the files, deleted the app from the simulator, quit xcode, restarted my mac, restored the files from the backup and there you go. It works!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
LoginViewController *loginVw = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
```

with

```
LoginViewController *loginVw = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

so the LoginViewController actually uses your .xib